# arrangements of the word **"ORACLE"** in which neither **O** follows **A** nor **A** follows **E** neither **E** follows **O,** is

Tags: combinatorics

finding number of arrangements of the word
**"ORACLE"** in which

neither **O** follows **A** nor **A** follows **E**  neither **E** follows **O,** is

Attempts: Total number of arrangement of the word **"ORACLE"** is $\displaystyle = 6! = 720$

but wna,t be able above number of arrangements, help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: there are varying interpretations here, that's why you have different answers. Could you clarify whether "follows" in the question means "follows immediately" or "follows at some point after"?

Answer (score 1):

In this answer "O does not follow A" is interpreted as: "AO" is not a substring of the arrangement.

Let e.g. $OAR$ denote the set of arrangements that contain "OAR" as a substring.

With inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:$$|AO\cup EA\cup OE|=|AO|+|EA|+|OE|-|EAO|-|AOE|-|OEA|+|\varnothing|=$$$$3|AO|-3|EAO|=3.5!-3.4!$$
So there are: $$6!-3.5!+3.4!=432$$possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If $O$ does not follow $A$ and $A$ does not follow $E$, the letters must occur in the order $OAE$, so the last condition cannot be met as well.

Hence, there is no such arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 conditions are

> O does not follow A $...(1)$
>
> A does not follows E $...(2)$
>
> E does not follows O $...(3)$

If the first two conditions are true, then

> O must not follow E  $...(4)$

$(3)$ and $(4)$ are contradictory. So, no arrangements possible